# Synchronization with google calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to synchronise all events with Google Calendar. I used the following code to do this:

```
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    calendarsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    calendarsArray = [[eventStore calendars] retain];
    EKCalendar *calendar = [calendarsArray objectAtIndex:1];
    [events setCalendar:calendar];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:events span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

But I am not getting google calendar at object at index(1). So Can anybody help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that calendars is deprecated in iOS 6 use this instead:

```
(NSArray *)calendarsForEntityType:(EKEntityType)entityType
```

Entity type then needs to be one of these:

```
typedef enum {
   EKEntityTypeEvent,
   EKEntityTypeReminder
} EKEntityType;
```

This should give you the expected result, more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/calendarsForEntityType:

Comment: Thanks @Notive I also used this,but still it's not working.Can you give some other solution.